# GCP Loadbalancer metric API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

when hitting https/backend_request_count API of GCP Loadbalancer, backend_target_name appears to be empty. What does it mean?

Comment: When you created the LB did you give the backend a name? Go back to the GCP Console and check.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, I have assigned backend service for each LB that I have created. Even though sometime backend_target_name is empty and also the values are coming. So, what does that values mean? To which backend service these vlues are related?

Comment: Add what you are seeing to your question.

Comment: 'https/backend_request_count' is a metric and not an API [1]. Can you please clarify what call you are making?
[1]https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp